# What algorithm can find multiple paths including choosing the best endpoints?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, path-finding

I was talking with my dad, he asked me:

"What algorithm you can use, so your online store can choose the best warehouse to send a product from?"

My reply was:

"Oh that is easy, just use Dijkstra, and use as weights for the nodes the monetary cost of the transportation, maybe with time factored in, the starting node being the client house"

Then he asked:

"Alright, but his list has a lot of different items, and many warehouses don't have all of them, you have to choose multiple warehouses to send the items from."

And then my brain froze.

So what algorithm I would use for that? I know I can brute-force Dijkstra, running many possibilities and then computing a result from the results of previous Dijkstra runs but is there a algorithm that can calculate multiple paths that result in the best overall result possible?

Comment: Looks like a variant of the *Vehicle Routing Problem*.

Comment: oooh, that is interesting, I never had heard of it before, I will read up on it!

Comment: Wow that is a really nice way to explain your question! I think you can also read about max flow problems with more than one source - not exactly what you are looking for but related.